# How to find multiple mongo db objects at once in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i am trying to run a search , it is working fine with **findOne** and recieving data but when i use find it just return some headers and prototypes like this

[response i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMyk9.png)

code

```
 let data = await client
.db("Movies")
.collection("movies")
.find();
console.log(data);
```

please tell me where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)

> The toArray() method returns an array that contains all the documents from a cursor. The method iterates completely the cursor, loading all the documents into RAM and exhausting the cursor.

so just try

```
 let data = await client
.db("Movies")
.collection("movies")
.find({}).toArray();
console.log(data);
```

Comment: _"...the type of result find is an array"_ - with NodeJS driver API, the result of `find` method is a _cursor_.